# Slow MySQL read/update database

Tags: mysql, performance, 32bit-64bit

I'm running a Windows 7 Enterprise, 64bit, Core i5 with 8GB of RAM and my college a much older Windows XP, 32 bit, Intel Centrino with 3GB of RAM. We are both running the WAMP stack but for some reason, my MySQL is acting really (!) slow... We benchmarked MySQL on both systems and here are the results:

```
                 64 bit vs. 32 bit
----------------------------------
Inserts:       8.666 vs.     4.641
Reads:       171.821 vs. 2.272.727
Update:       78.003 vs. 1.923.077
```

So, does anyone have an idea what causes this massive delay, despite my system should perform much faster with his specifics!

Comment: "Apache"? How did you benchmark the database? direct SQL or through some script (e.g. php) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant MySQL. I benchmarked the database using a PHP script (this one: http://unbeknownst.net/?p=321)

Comment: What you need to do is to isolate the problem ... it could be one of many many things ... start by comparing the WAMP services' versions on the two machines. Also, make sure your hardware (harddrives and memory) are fine (by using some sort of benchmark). Once everything look fine ... start digging MySQL configuration.

Comment: Also, are you using the 64bit MySQL server on the Win7 machine?

Comment: I do run the 64bit MySQL. It's a brandnew machine so I don't think anything is wrong with my hardware... But I can do some benchmarking, sure. Any advice for some good tools? I think my MySQL configuration is just fine. I followed every "boost performance MySQL" there is, I even replaced the `my.ini` file with the `my-large.ini`. And I gave it every available memorysource I've got.

Comment: did you benchmark for MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I benchmarked for MyISAM

Comment: Do you have any firewall/IP blocker/fancy-antivirus/useless-security-suite enabled on your machine? If so, try disabling it and re-run the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. In your `php.ini` file, there is somewhere a line `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1`. Change the value to 0, 1 or 2 and see what the best performance gives. My performance got a boost by factor 30!

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where IPv6 was causing a delay on my WAMP install running on a virtual server. It was off in the Network Settings but had to be disabled in the registry. [Hey, Dude, Where’s My Localhost?](http://bobstrand.com/totm/2010/04/hey-dude-wheres-my-localhost/) is a good write-up of the problem.

My configuration was: Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) + Apache 2.4 VC9 (32-bit) + MySQL 5.5 (64-bit) + PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32-bit) + MediaWiki 1.19.